# How to configure i18n-ally for VSCode to work with Vue Single-File Components (SFC)?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n, i18n-ally

I use Vue Single-File Components, containing `<i18n lang="json"></i18n>` block as a part of my `*.vue` files.
I have also my localisation files for the entire project in a separate folder.

I have tried to configure [i18n-ally](https://github.com/lokalise/i18n-ally) extension for VSCode, and everything works fine with the localisation files. But I can't configure the extension to find and use the translation blocks inside my vue-files.

I have tried to add vue-files into the path:

```
"i18n-ally.localesPaths": [
    "./frontend/locales",
    "./frontend/**/*.vue"
]
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I configure it in a proper way?